# Are questions about performance a good fit for code golf?

Tags: discussion

For example I have a running program in Python that solves game X. The performances are good enough for me and I don't feel like I can improve it. Now I am curious to know how much this could still be improved. For example, in my solution I am not taking advantage of multiple cores on my processor. Also, I think it could be rewritten in another language that would execute even faster, and so on.. Is it a question for Code Golf, or for Stack Overflow ? Neither ?

Comment: You could do this here, but you'd need to set it up something like this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26323/9498

Comment: [There's a tag for that.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

Comment: Since you've already got a working code, you can post it to [codereview.se]

Comment: Even if it doesn't 'belong' here, consider if it may make an interesting question/challenge anyway.

Comment: @JanDvorak It might nevertheless be an interesting challenge.